# How to write postgres select queries for arrays in JSONB columns?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around querying JSON arrays in postgres. For example:

Given a Postgres table `foobar` with the JSONB column `data` like...

```
db=# select * from foobar;
 id |             data              
----+--------------------------------------------
  1 | [[true, true], [true, false]] 
  2 | [[true, true], [true, true]]  
  3 | [[true, true], [true, true], [true, true]]  
(3 rows)
```

How would I write a select query that would select only the row which contains only `true` values in each array in `data` and whose array is of length 2. (i.e., row `id = 2` in the example above)?

Answer (score 1):

Just compare it with a reference:

```
select *
from foobar
where data = '[[true, true], [true, true]]'
```